# How to do Integer division in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have trouble with integer division in Dart as it gives me error: *'Breaking on exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'c'.'*

Here's the following code:

```dart
int a = 500;
int b = 250;
int c;

c = a / b; // <-- Gives warning in Dart Editor, and throws an error in runtime.
```

As you see, I was expecting that the result should be 2, or say, even if division of 'a' or 'b' would have a result of a float/double value, it should be converted directly to integer value, instead of throwing error like that.

I have a workaround by using .round()/.ceil()/.floor(), but this won't suffice as in my program, this little operation is critical as it is called thousands of times in one game update (or you can say in requestAnimationFrame).

I have not found any other solution to this yet, any idea? Thanks.

Dart version: 1.0.0_r30798

Answer (score 103, accepted):

That is because **Dart uses `double` to represent all numbers** in `dart2js`. You can get interesting results, if you play with that:

Code:

```
int a = 1; 
a is int; 
a is double;
```

Result:

```
true
true
```

Actually, it is recommended to use type `num` when it comes to numbers, unless you have strong reasons to make it `int` (in for loop, for example). If you want to keep using `int`, use truncating division like this:

```
int a = 500;
int b = 250;
int c;

c = a ~/ b;
```

Otherwise, I would recommend to utilize `num` type.

Comment: Dart uses doubles to represent numbers only in dart2js. The VM correctly distinguishes between the two types. Please update your answer.

Comment: Just a small update: Even the Dart VM makes a double out of an integer division, even if it would not result in fractions. ~/ helped though, thanks!

Comment: Even `num a = 1.0; print(a is int); print(a is double);` yields `true` twice if executed in the dartpad.

Answer (score 80):

Integer division is

```dart
c = a ~/ b;
```

you could also use

```dart
c = (a / b).floor();
c = (a / b).ceil();
```

if you want to define how fractions should be handled.

Answer (score 21):

**Short Answer**

Use `c = a ~/ b`.

**Long Answer**

According to the docs, `int` are numbers without a decimal point, while `double` are numbers with a decimal point.

Both `double` and `int` are subtypes of `num`.

When two integers are divided using the `/` operator, the result is evaluated into a `double`. And the `c` variable was initialized as an integer. There are at least two things you can do:

1. Use `c = a ~/ b`.

The `~/` operator returns an `int`.

2. Use `var c;`. This creates a dynamic variable that can be assigned to any type, including a `double` and `int` and `String` etc.

Answer (score 20):

### Truncating division operator

You can use the [**truncating division operator `~/`**](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/num/operator_truncate_divide.html) to get an integer result from a division operation:

```dart
4 ~/ 2; // 2 (int)
```

### Division operator

The [regular division operator `/`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/num/operator_divide.html) will always return a `double` value at runtime (see the docs):

```dart
for (var i = 4; i == 4; i = 3) {
  i / 2; // 2 (double)
}
```

#### Runtime versus compile time

You might have noticed that I wrote a loop for the second example (for the regular division operator) instead of `4 / 2`.

The reason for this is the following:
When an expression can be *evaluated at compile time*, it will be simplified at that stage and also be typed accordingly. The compiler would simply convert `4 / 2` to `2` at compile time, which is then obviously an `int`. The loop prevents the compiler from evaluating the expression.

As long as your division happens **at runtime** (i.e. with variables that cannot be predicted at compile time), the return types of the `/` (`double`) and `~/` (`int`) operators will be the types you will see for your expressions at runtime.

See [this fun example](https://twitter.com/timsneath/status/1355617006825820161?s=20) for further reference.

### Conclusion

Generally speaking, the regular division operator `/` always [returns a `double` value](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/num/operator_divide.html) and [truncate divide](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/num/operator_truncate_divide.html) can be used to get an `int` result instead.

Compiler optimization might, however, cause some funky results :)